# Varios listados paginados en una misma página

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Buenas:
Tengo dos listados diferentes en la misma página, con una paginación en cada listado.

[image: Listings]

Cuando pulso en una de las paginaciónes, por ejemplo, en página dos, los dos listados van a la página dos, de cada listado.

¿Como podría hacer en Laravel, para que se me recarge solo un listado?

Este es mi controlador:

```
 public function index($id,Request $request)
{             
    $holidays = Vacations::where('type','holidays')->where('id_user', '=', $id)->paginate(3);       
    $permit = Vacations::where('type','permit')->where('id_user', '=', $id)->paginate(3);
       return view('vacations.index',compact('holidays','permit','id'))
            ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Miguel please translate your question, this is the Spanish site.

Comment: Bienvenido @MiguelHerrerosCejas,  El idioma oficial de este sitio es español, traduce tu pregunta por favor. Debes leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y evites sea cerrada o con puntuación negativa. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Hecho. Muchas gracias por el aviso.

Comment: podrias mostrar el codigo de tu vista, donde creas tus dos tablas